# GWT ListEditor implementing HasEditorErrors, custom error marking for ListEditor

Tags: validation, gwt, bean-validation

I have this ListEditor that takes care of editing the licenses for a Customer. In my `CustomerEditor`, thie `LicensesEditor` is bound to path licenses, which is of type `List<License>>`.

> Customer (1)--> (many) Licenses (java.util.List)

Now, the validation rules state that at least one license per Customer is required. The constraint violations work perfectly. But how do I implement HasEditorErrors for a ListEditor ...  I want to provide my own error marking.

**What type do I inject for the generic parameter T of HasEditorErrors < T >** ??

```
public interface HasEditorErrors<T> extends Editor<T>
```

The signature for the ListEditor is as follows ...

```
public class LicensesEditor extends Composite implements IsEditor<ListEditor<License, LicenseInListEditor>>
```

I tried to implement `HasEditorErrors<List<License>>` which gives at runtime the error :

> [DEBUG] [klawtapp] - Descending into licenses
>   [ERROR] [klawtapp] - Could not find a getter for path  editor in proxy type java.util.List

If I implement `HasEditorErrors<LicensesEditor>`

> [ERROR] [klawtapp] Could not find a getter for path editor in proxy
>   type com.klawt.screen.ui.customers.LicensesEditor

Keeping a question mark in HasEditorErrors as implemented interface gives compile time error :

> The type LicensesEditor cannot extend or implement HasEditorErrors.
>   A supertype may not specify any wildcard  LicensesEditor.java

Anybody ?

*UPDATE,full code below :*

```
public class LicensesEditor extends Composite implements IsEditor<ListEditor<License, LicenseInListEditor>> {

    @UiField
    Image validationErrorIcon;

    interface LicensesEditorUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, LicensesEditor> {
    }

    private static LicensesEditorUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(LicensesEditorUiBinder.class);

    @UiField
    VerticalPanel container;

    ListEditor<License, LicenseInListEditor> editor;

    public LicensesEditor() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        editor = ListEditor.of(new LicenseInListEditorSource());
        clearErrors();
    }

    @Override
    public ListEditor<License, LicenseInListEditor> asEditor() {
        return editor;
    }

    public void addLicense(License emailAddress) {
        editor.getList().add(emailAddress);
        if (emailAddress.getAdministrator()) {
            setPrimary(editor.getList().size() - 1);
        }
    }

    public void remove(int index) {
        editor.getList().remove(index);
    }

    public void update(int index, License emailAddress) {
        editor.getList().remove(index);
        editor.getList().add(index, emailAddress);
    }

    /**
     * make the phonenumber at the index the primary phonenumber and the other
     * phone numbers not primary.
     * 
     * @param index
     */
    public void setPrimary(int index) {
        int loop = 0;

        for (License emailAddress : Collections.unmodifiableList(editor.getList())) {
            emailAddress.setAdministrator(index == loop);
            update(loop, emailAddress);
            loop++;
        }
    }

    private class LicenseInListEditorSource extends EditorSource<LicenseInListEditor> {

        @Override
        public LicenseInListEditor create(final int index) {
            LicenseInListEditor editor = new LicenseInListEditor();
            editor.addDeleteHandler(new ListEditorDeleteEventHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onEditorEvent(ListEditorDeleteEvent event) {
                    remove(index);
                }
            });
            editor.addUpdateHandler(new EditorUpdateEventHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onEditorUpdate(EditorUpdateEvent event) {
                    License emailAddress = (License) event.getUpdated();
                    update(index, emailAddress);
                    if (emailAddress.getAdministrator()) {
                        setPrimary(index);
                    }
                }
            });
            container.insert(editor, index);
            updateOddEven();
            return editor;
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(LicenseInListEditor subEditor) {
            container.remove(subEditor);
            updateOddEven();
        }

        @Override
        public void setIndex(LicenseInListEditor editor, int index) {
            container.insert(editor, index);
            updateOddEven();
        }

        public void updateOddEven() {
            for (int widgetIndex = 0; widgetIndex < container.getWidgetCount(); widgetIndex++) {
                container.getWidget(widgetIndex).setStyleName(KlawtResources.INSTANCE.form().listEditorEven(),
                        (widgetIndex % 2 == 0));
                container.getWidget(widgetIndex).setStyleName(KlawtResources.INSTANCE.form().listEditorOdd(),
                        (widgetIndex % 2 == 1));
            }
        }

    }

    // @Override
    // public void showErrors(List<EditorError> errors) {
    // StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // int errorCount = 0;
    // for (EditorError editorError : errors) {
    // if (errorCount > 0) {
    // sb.append("\n");
    // }
    // errorCount++;
    // sb.append(editorError.getMessage());
    // }
    // if (errorCount == 0) {
    // clearErrors();
    // } else {
    // container.setStyleName(KlawtResources.INSTANCE.form().formError(), true);
    // validationErrorIcon.setVisible(true);
    // validationErrorIcon.setTitle(sb.toString());
    // }
    // }

    private void clearErrors() {
        container.setStyleName(KlawtResources.INSTANCE.form().formError(), false);
        validationErrorIcon.setVisible(false);
        validationErrorIcon.setTitle("");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this because it is a list interface and I need to have an implementation like ArrayList ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` isn't the problem, mixing and matching `Editor` and `IsEditor` is when combined with (I suspect - without posting more than type decls it is hard to say) some internals of `LicensesEditor` (namely, the access modifier of the `ListEditor` member, which I think you called `editor`).

The `IsEditor<E>` interface is used to say "I'm not myself an editor, but I can provide one", and its non-private members that implements `Editor` will be ignored, but the framework will still descend into the non-private editors in `E`. Since (I suspect) your `LicensesEditor` internals actually has a non-private editor member,

So where does this leave you? Several choices that seem to make sense to me:

- Stop using `IsEditor` so you can implement `HasEditorErrors`. Instead, make `LicensesEditor extends Composite implements Editor<List<Licenses>>, HasEditorErrors<List<Licenses>>` (though technically the first `Editor` is covered by the second, but I find it helps readability). Now you still need a ListEditor member (as you almost certainly currently have already), but annotate it with `@Path("")` to indicate that it should edit the same value that the entire editor got.
- Use `IsEditor`, but make it generic on both `HasEditorErrors` and `ListEditor` - make a ListEditor subclass that also implements `HasEditorErrors` and has error support. This allows you to still extend `Composite` in the wrapping class. Turn this around, and you have...
- Extend `ListEditor`, and implement `IsWidget` instead of extending Composite. This achieves the same effect as the first option (you can make `LicensesEditor` implement `HasEditorErrors` by getting rid of `IsEditor`), without using `@Path` to make things make sense. Now, instead of calling `Composite.initWidget`, keep a reference to the widget, and return it for `IsWidget.asWidget()`.
- Last, do nothing. From the `IsEditor` Javadocs:

  > It is legal for a type to implement both Editor and IsEditor. In this case,
  >   the Editor returned from {@link #asEditor()} will be a co-Editor of the
  >   IsEditor instance.

  This means that `LicensesEditor` should be a valid `Editor - any non-private Editor member should either be changed to private or tagged with`@Ignore`.

Comment: this will take some testing ... I will report my findings back.

Comment: you were right that i had an internal editor. I went for option 1 from your answer, changed sig to public class LicensesEditor extends Composite implements Editor<List<License>>, HasEditorErrors<List<License>> and added @Editor.Path("") to the internal editor...and success :) thx for the great answer.